# Other keys for error messages in Django model

Tags: django, model

When you want to set error messages in Django model field use:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='password', 
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-lg'}),
        error_messages={
            'required': ("required"),
            '?': ("..."),

        }
    )
```

How can we fine other keys like `required`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message keys include `null, blank, invalid, invalid_choice, unique, and unique_for_date`.

For Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/error_messages-django-built-in-field-validation/